# Backbone.Models: How to do deep toJSON serialization with embedded Collections?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone Model that contains a collection:

```
var Stream =  Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        dummyField: "1",
        excludedUsers: new Backbone.Collection()
    }
});

var s = new Stream;
s.get('excludedUsers').add( {name:'Stefan'} );
console.log(s.toJSON())
```

yields:

```
{ dummyField: '1',
  excludedUsers: 
   { length: 1,
     models: [ [Object] ],
     _byId: {},
     _byCid: { c1: [Object] } } }
```

instead of the "expected":

```
 { 
      dummyField: '1',
      excludedUsers: [ {name:'Stefan'} ]
 }
```

because Backbone isn't deeply JSONing the Model. The only way of working around is to [override the toJSON method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958747/backbone-js-overwritting-tojson) on the Stream's prototype but that won't help for other cases. Is there a general/better solution (besides the heavy [Backbone.Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) plugin) already?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to overwrite the `Backbone.Collection.toJSON()` function directly or make a new collection to which you extend all your other collections:

```
var MyDefaultCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    toJSON: function() {
        //Your code here
    }
});
var Stream = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        dummyField: "1",
        excludedUsers: new MyDefaultCollection()
    }
});
//You could also extend it
var NewCollection = MyDefaultCollection.extend({
    //custom code here
});
```

It's just theory, I've never coded it, so any feedback on my idea is welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function flattenModel(model) {
    return _.mapValues(model.attributes, flatten);
}

function flattenCollection(collection) {
    return collection.map(flattenModel);
}

function flatten(object) {
    if (object instanceof Backbone.Model) {
        return flattenModel(object);
    } else if (object instanceof Backbone.Collection) {
        return flattenCollection(object);
    }

    return object;
}
```

This will return an object, and then:

```
JSON.stringify(flatten(model))
```

Note that [_.mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) is a handy method from lodash, so you should use that or just port that method.